# UDP: Read frame a NEW frame from client every x seconds

Tags: c, linux, udp

I have a udp client (**I have no control over the source code**) that is constantly sending data frames, one frame per 500ms, and I have a udp server that checks the last frame every 5 seconds.

The problem is that this udp server doesn't read the last frame but only the next frame in the udp buffer from the operating system.

```
        n = recvfrom(server_sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &new_dax[eqpID].clientaddr,
                 &new_dax[eqpID].clientlen);
```

With this code if my udpclient is sending :

FRAME 1 ->500ms

FRAME 2->500ms

FRAME 3->500ms

FRAME X->500ms

My udp server receives firstly FRAME 1, and then after 5 seconds when I try to read the frame from the client the server receveives FRAME 2 instead of FRAME X.

How do I get the last frame received? I tried closing the server socket and opening it again when I want to receive the last frame but this is consuming to much resources. Is it possible without closing the server socket?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recvmmsg()` to receive a whole bunch of messages at once.  So in your case, you expect to receive about 10 messages per read, so set up buffers for 12-15 messages and just call `recvmmsg()` once, then ignore all but the last message.

You'll want to use the `MSG_WAITFORONE` flag, so that `recvmmsg()` doesn't block until all 12-15 messages are received--you only expect to receive 9-11 or so.

Comment: How do set the flag so that it doenst block until 12 or 15?

Comment: @hydros30: You just pass `MSG_WAITFORONE`.